# In QGIS 3, is the vector -> openstreet map conversion missing?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to convert osm to shapefile but I can't find the 
Vector > OpenStreetMap > Import Topology from XML

[image]

Comment: You can use Layer - Add Layer - Add Vector Layer instead. Data are opened with GDAL and this manual applies http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html.

Comment: The old OSM importer from QGIS 2 was dropped in QGIS 3 due to lots of unresolved bugs. The QuickOSM plugin also enables to read osm raw files.